# How to set a request for a generic without the type in define?

Tags: rust

Excuse me for my English.

I'm developing a version of Haskell's Parsec library for Rust. When I try to define a type alias for parsec, like the define in Swift:

```
struct Parsec<T, S:CollectionType> {
    typealias Parser = (BasicState<S>)->Result<T, SimpleError<S.Index>>
}
```

I want to write:

```
pub type Result<T> = result::Result<Arc<T>, SimpleError>;
pub type Parsec<T, R, S> where S:State<T> = Box<FnMut(&mut S)->Result<R>>;
```

But it has a compiler error:

> Compiling raskell v0.1.0 (file:///Users/march/jobs/raskell)
>   src/parsec/atom.rs:7:45: 7:74 error: 
>   type parameter `T` is unused [E0091]
>   src/parsec/atom.rs:7 pub type Parsec where S:State = BoxResult>;

But if I ignore it, will got some difficult about type derive. Just like some parameters with `State<T>`, should be a generic type, but the compiler can't know the type at compilation time.

There's a complete [Swift 2.0 edition](https://github.com/Dwarfartisan/sparsec), but the unit testing isn't completed. There's a [golang edition](https://github.com/Dwarfartisan/goparsec) with more unit tests and a [lisp like sample project](https://github.com/Dwarfartisan/gisp). Maybe these projects can help me show the idea and my problems.

The [Rust edition that I am writing](https://github.com/Dwarfartisan/ruskell) cannot be built. If you try to `cargo build`, you will see some errors.

Comment: Please update your example code with a [MCVE](/help/mcve); hopefully one that can be compiled on [the playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/). This helps you narrow down the error, and helps us concentrate on solving your problem, and not some extra problem we add by filling in missing parts of your code.

Comment: Sorry for the example. It is a part of a  small project about 3k lines(This data from the golang edition). The state is a iterator with index state and the Parsec is a define for all parser. So,  may be I need create a sample 100 line or more for run a basic logic. I think it should too large for a question. So I level the complete project for the other language edition. Them written by me too. I'm going try to create a smaller sample for this question.

Comment: Yes, 3k lines is far too big, but we can wait for you to make a 10 line example that produces the same error ^_^. I like to create a new branch in git and then just delete everything that isn't needed for that line of code. Sometimes, you can try copying your problem line into a new file and make stub structs / traits.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I will come back with the small sample. It is am 2:05 in China. Good night. XD